An Interesting Number- it's square and cubes span $0-9$
Let $m$ be a natural number such that $$m^2= ABCD$$ and $$m^3= EFGHIJ$$ where $$A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J$$ represent the digits $$0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9$$ in some order (each digit appears exactly once across $ABCD$ and $EFGHIJ$). Determine the value of $m$.
I am curious about this question because while I was composing some questions, I ended up wondering about this. Howver since I am not able to solve this, I am eager to know the solution.
Attempt- $1000000m^2 + m^3= ABCDEFGHIJ$ whose sum of digits being $45$ is divisible by $3$ hence $m^2 + m^3$ is divisible by $3$. Thus modulo $3$, $m$ must be either $0$ or $ 2$. Morever it is clear that $ 47 \leq m \leq 99$. It is also clear that m doesn't end with $0,1$ and $5$, so I think I have reduced the possibilities to some $25$ natural numbers. But I am not sure what else I can do.

$25$  is small enough that testing all $25$ candidates might be easier than coming up with more clever ideas.

@AndreasBlass, Sure. But in an exam I don't think we can expect a student compute the square and cubes of $25$ natural numbers. One small mistake and one might just miss the correct values of $m$. Plus math is all about clever ideas. Isn't it?

No, math is not all about clever ideas, it's about ideas that work. Sometimes trying to force a theoretical approach is way much work than simply doing some calculations.

You're right: That is probably not a good exam question. -- And your attempt only puts $m^2$ in front of $m^3$, but the question does not have such a restriction.

Proofwiki and Quora have essentially brute force solutions like what you suggested.

@Henriksupportsthecommunity, yes unfortunately.

This is rather a short programming exercise, the solution is quickly found, since there are a few values for $m$, so that the square has four digits.
sage: for m in [32..99]:
....:     abcd, efghij = str(m^2), str(m^3)
....:     if (len(abcd), len(efghij), len(set(abcd + efghij))) == (4, 6, 10):
....:         print(m, abcd, efghij)
....: 
69 4761 328509


For a "human" solution, we already have a list of conditions on $m$, but there is still to much to check. So let us recollect:

The number $\overline{ABCDEFGHIJ}$ is modulo nine the same as $m^2+m^3=\overline{ABCD}+\overline{EFGHIJ}$, which is the same as
$A+B+C+D+E+F+G+H+I+J=0+1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9=45$,
so it is divisible by nine. So either $m$ is a multiple of $3$, or $m+1$ is a multiple of $9$.

The last digit is not $0,1,5,6$.

$(D,J)$ is among $(4,8)$, $(9,7)$, $(6, 4)$, $(9, 3)$, $(4,2)$, $(1,9)$.

$m^3$ is between $102345$ and $987654$, so $m$ is between $102345^{1/3}\approx 46.775$ and $987654^{1/3}$, so $m$ is between $47$ and $98$.

The following numbers $m$ are so far to be checked:
$$
[48, 53, 54, 57, 62, 63, 69, 72, 78, 84, 87, 89, 93, 98, 99]\ .
$$

Because of $62^2=3844$, $63^2=3969$, these two numbers are leaving the list.

Also $48^3=110592$, $53^3=148877$, $54^3=157464$, $57^3=185193$, $62^3=238328$, $63^3=250047$,
$72^3=373248$,
$78^3=474552$,
$87^3=658503$,
$89^3=704969$,
$98^3=941192$, and each cube has a repeating digit.

There remain only $69$, $84$, $93$. So we have to compute:
$$
\begin{aligned}
69^2 &= 4761\ , & 69^3 &= 328509\ ,\\
84^2 &= 7056\ , & 84^3 &= 592704\ ,\\
93^2 &= 8649\ , & 93^3 &= 804357\ ,
\end{aligned}
$$
and only $69$ works.



I think your notes about $1234$ and $123456$ are neglecting to consider even smaller numbers like $1023$ and $102345$.

@2'59'2 Yes, thanks for pointing it out! I have to adjust! Done by now...
